# How can you adjust the contrast/gamma of both IPS and non IPS displays in the classic BIOS as well as in the UEFI BIOS?

Tags: bios, uefi, configure, contrast, gamma

And no, I'm not asking how to adjust contrast/gamma at the OS level. Because that can only be a bad substitute, since one would have to make a corresponding setting and partly also still needed additional software, in each operating system again, from which one starts.

How can you adjust the contrast/gamma of both IPS and non IPS displays in the classic BIOS as well as in the UEFI BIOS?

Comment: Assuming Windows, just use Color Calibration. That will do what you need.

Comment: My own BIOS (Lenovo) does not adjust this.  So I am not sure about the BIOS feature.

Comment: Again, I'm not asking how to adjust contrast/gamma at the OS level. Because that can only be a bad substitute, since one would have to make a corresponding setting and partly also still needed additional software, in each operating system again, from which one starts.

Comment: Some PC monitor, TV and so on offer contrast configuration like this. But Notebooks and Handys possible dont offer this by standard.

Comment: BIOS/UEFI does not handle the monitors at all.

Comment: You can't. BIOS/UEFI is not sufficiently large or complex enough to contain drivers for every graphics card in existence, which is what is needed to be able to drive the display outputs to configure things like brightness and contrast. Without drivers you are limited to what the display itself allows. You can either set up each operating system correctly, or set up the display itself correctly.

Comment: Some normal Monitor can like this. Dont need a hight level operating system.

Comment: First question is, *can* it be done even. If not then this how question makes zero sense.

Comment: Unless you have a unique system that DOES offer this function, you can't. I have worked with a large number of computers over the past 25 years and having observed this function at all on any of them. IF a computer offers this function it will be via a method unique to that system, and so I don't see how this can be answered well here unless you already have a very specific computer model chosen. If you don't, I recommend you take a few steps back, drop your assumptions, and tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to do it entirely using the OSD controls on each display… assuming you could find some way to load a suitable image to work from. BOIS/UEFI are not interested in colour profiles at all. They don't load until the OS loads.

Then, once each OS was running, you'd then have to re-do it to adjust the icc colour profile each uses as default.

You may get more mileage by setting the screen up properly in one OS - for which you really need a hardware colorimeter rather than guesswork - then port your icc profile over to the other OS.